# iOS 4 UIWebView Trouble with Javascript

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, ios4

I have code that works great in 3.2 and earlier. The javascript from my UIWebView Load - never seems to execute... Any idea what changed with 4.0 that might cause a problem...?

- my current code has a bunch of javascript in the page to load and format - one of the things is a variable that indicates the javascript prep is done... I am checking that at 0.5 second intervals with a call
  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"fsready"]

When that is set to 1 - I proceed... I have tried showing the window etc -- it looks like it never loads. I have taken the html that I am loading and confirmed it all works in Safari -- even mobile safari. Again - running the same thing on 3.2 or earlier works find on the device as well...

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

we ended up finding that there is an issue with how iOS 4.0 handles the accelerometer.  We ended up taking the accelerometer code out of our app.. and everything started working.